# Notation for the reverse identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, hankel-matrices

I'm wondering if there's a canonical notation for the reverse identity matrix, i.e.
$$
?=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0 & 0\\
1&0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Sometimes I've seen $J_n$ but I'm not quite satysfied since I usually use this notation for the antisymmetric version of this matrix. Is it a standard notation?

Comment: that being said, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix uses the notation $J_n$ as well and cites Horn's [Matrix Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=O7sgAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: While $J_n$ is a relatively popular notation for the reversal matrix, I don't think it's a standard notation. Many people use $J_n$ to denote something else, such as an $n\times n$ Jordan block or the all-one matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a widely used symbol for that. I would consider the permutation 
$$
\overset{\tiny \leftarrow}{\sigma}:=\begin{pmatrix} n & n-1 & \ldots &2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
and then refer to that matrix as $P_\overset{\tiny \leftarrow}{\sigma}$. You can of course drop the small arrow if it seems too heavy, or use another (Greek) letter for the permutation.